# C# Get return object of CreatedAtRoute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit

I have a controller method which returns a CreatedAtRoute object. How can I extract the returned object?

My test class (which calls the controller):

```
[Test]
public void AddUser(){
  AppUser au= new AppUser();
  GreenCardController gc = new GreenCardController();
  ActionResult<AppUser> res = gc.UpdateArgosUser(au); //<-- How can I turn this into an AppUser object?
  //var temp=res.Value; //this didnt have the Object
  Assert.AreEqual(res.FirstName,"")
}
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult<AppUser> UpdateArgosUser([FromBody]AppUser au)
{
     return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GreenCardController.GetArgosUser), new 
                   { userid = au.UserId }, au);
}
```

When I paused this in debug mode `res.Result.Value` seemed to be what I was looking for, but I get the error:

> ActionResult does not contain a definition for 'Value'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the desired values from within the returned `ActionResult<AppUser>`, casting to the known types to get access to the desired members.

Since the controller call `return CreatedAtRoute(...)`, then you need to access the `ActionResult<TResult>.Result` property to get the returned `ActionResult` from the controller.

From there it is a matter of getting the stored value object within the object result.

```
[Test]
public void AddUser(){
    //Arrange
    AppUser expected = new AppUser();
    GreenCardController controller = new GreenCardController();

    //Act
    ActionResult<AppUser> actionResult = controller.UpdateArgosUser(expected);
    CreatedAtRouteResult result = actionResult.Result as CreatedAtRouteResult;
    AppUser actual = result.Value as AppUser;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```